# impresión por consola en método en java (Android) no muestra lo que deseo

Tags: java, android-studio, hilos, activity, android-asynctask

Tengo la siguiente clase DescargarDatos que extiende de AsyncTask y ejecuta en su doInBackground al método sincronizarGetZonas(), este método realiza una petición StringRequest a través de tipo GET, yo quiero capturar mediante mensajes por consola cuando la conexión es exitosa o fallida, para ello uso las cadenas "OK" y "FAIL", pero tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

dentro del método sincronizarGetZonas() la salida por consola es: (PRINT_1 OK)
pero dentro de la clase DescargarDatos la salida por consola es: (Respuesta del GET: FAIL)

efectivamente la conexión se realiza exitosamente, pero no tengo como validarlo porque la variable que uso para capturar el valor llega con el parámetro incorrecto.

Tampoco entiendo porqué en el orden de la consola primero se imprime (Respuesta del GET: FAIL) antes que (PRINT_1 OK) si estoy imprimiendo el mensaje por pantalla en el método: @Override onPostExecute() en donde se supone que ya finalizó la tarea:

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class ActivityLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

String variableGlobal = "FAIL";


 private class DescargarDatos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
     private ProgressDialog mProgressBarControles;
     @Override
     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            sincronizarGetZonas(ActivityLogin.this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        mProgressBarControles = new ProgressDialog(ActivityLogin.this);
        mProgressBarControles.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressBarControles.setTitle(" Descargando Información del Servidor ... ");
        mProgressBarControles.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressBarControles.show();
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        mProgressBarControles.cancel();
        System.out.println("Respuesta del GET: " + variableGlobal);
        Toast.makeText(ActivityLogin.this, variableGlobal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  }

 public void sincronizarGetZonas(Context context){
    final AdminSQLiteOpenHelper database = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(ActivityLogin.this);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, WEBSERVICE.GET_ZONAS, new 
            Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        database.insertarZonasNuevas(object.getInt(DBLocal.TB_ZONA.ID),
                                object.getString(DBLocal.TB_ZONA.NOMBRE),
                                db);
                    }

                    variableGlobal = "OK";
                    System.out.println("PRINT_1 " + variableGlobal );
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("PRINT_2 " + variableGlobal );
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("PRINT_3 " + variableGlobal );
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Salida por consola:

```
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x763f68d000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x763f68d000,bufferCount=3)
Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x763f68d000)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x763f7c7000,api=1)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@f8896fc[ ]
I/System.out: Respuesta del GET: FAIL
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = 
false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x75df1dd000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x75df1dd000,bufferCount=3)
Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x75df1dd000)
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
[OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out: PRINT_1 OK
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x75df1dd000,api=1)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{dd99ba6 V.E...... ......ID 
0,0-96,98}
I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 2, oppidx_max 2, oppidx_min 0
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: Me parece que tu problema es de sincronismo. Cuando entras en la función `sincronizarGetZonas` haces el request que se ejecuta de forma **asíncrona**. Esto significa que `onResponse` se ejecutará cuando sea. Pero tu función `sincronizarGetZonas` continua, y termina y hace terminar la tarea. Y luego cuando se produce la respuesta se ejecuta el `onResponse`. Tienes que hacer algo para esperar a que termine.

Comment: Estás mezclando `AsyncTask` y `Volley`, dos librerías que hacen tareas similares. No es la primera vez que veo esto aquí, no sé si hay algún tutorial o en algún sitio se está enseñando esta **pésima práctica** de mezclar librerías que en esencia serían redundantes. Te recomendaría que aclares un poco tu código decidiéndote por `Volley`, pues `AsyncTask` ya ha sido declarada obsoleta. Además, `Volley` es mucho más simple y más rápida.

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy usando AsyncTask porque dentro de el tengo varios métodos que se conectan a un webservice, no los incluí en la pregunta porque quise primero saber que ocasionaba el inconveniente, temporalmente solucioné con un Thread dentro de un do while para esperar la respuesta de la otra tarea, pero. ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar varios Volley que se conectan al servidor sin agruparlos en un AsyncTask?

Comment: AsyncTask es obsoleto, por tanto te recomiendo en primer lugar que migres todo tu código a Volley, porque además mezclando librerías el código no funcionará y aunque funcione no es una buena práctica y terminaría dando problemas. En cuanto a lo de hacer varias peticiones lo veo complicado, sobre todo porque las peticiones de red son asíncronas, por lo que podría ser muy complicado sincronizar dos peticiones. Si el WebService es tuyo lo propio sería programar un tipo de petición que te traiga de una vez lo que estás necesitando en esas dos peticiones.